# AbstractCreatorProcessor class not found error

Tags: java, tomcat9

While setting up adopt openjdk 8 with Tomcat 9 with my existing application, I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/stream/buffer/AbstractCreatorProcessor
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:363)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:321)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:207)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:114)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:707)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.createJaxWsService(LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.java:162)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.prepare(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:339)
```

It was working fine with Oracle JDK, is there anything I am missing for openjdk?

Comment: What Java version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For openjdk you need the JAX-WS dependency library `streambuffer.jar`.

You can download it from [here](http://jax-ws.java.net/) or, if you use Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.stream.buffer/streambuffer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
    <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```